# The bounty expiration shown in the notification message is different from the expiration shown in the question

Tags: support, bounty, notifications

I logged in early on *Ask Different*, and I have got a message about the expiration of the bounty I offered. When I clicked on the question link, I noticed the question was reporting the bounty would expire one day earlier.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two days your question will cease to be promoted as a bounty question. However, you are given an extra day to select your bounty answer before one is selected automatically.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the sentence in the question page says "ending in two days" because an answer given after 3 days is not eligible for the bounty, while the bounty effectively expires after 3 days, which means I cannot anymore select to which answer I give the bounty. Is it correct?

Comment: @kiamlaluno from everyone else's perspective, the bounty ends in 2 days, but you have an additional day, so that's why the system was telling you that you had 3 days

Comment: Ooh - that is subtle. The expiration time for me to award the bounty is different than the public promotion period. A very nice touch despite the confusion.